# Getting jQuery-inserted DOM elements without requerying for element after insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference, dom

Assuming I insert anything in my DOM with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), like so:

```
$('#someselector').prepend('<img src="/img/myimage.gif" id="someid" />');
```

Is there a way in jQuery to get a `jQuery` object referencing this new image, without having to do an extra search like

```
var myImage = $('#someselector #someid');
```

???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('#someselector')
    .prepend('<img src="/img/myimage.gif" id="someid" />')
    .find('#someid');
```

Or if there's only one img:

```
$('#someselector')
    .prepend('<img src="/img/myimage.gif" id="someid" />')
    .find('img');
```

Alternatively:

```
$('<img src="/img/myimage.gif" id="someid" />').prependTo('#someselector')
```

Comment: Yes, that last one is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Make it into an jQuery object *before* prepending it:

```
var $img = $('<img src="/img/myimage.gif" id="someid" />');    
$('#someselector').prepend($img);    
$img.foo();
```

Comment: That's an okay solution, but I like the one line solution from qwertymk better.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without creating a jQuery object before and without having an Id:

```
var $img = $('#someselector')
            .prepend('<img src="/img/myimage.gif" />')
            .find(':first');
```