# Delete new jQuery prepended node after 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting jQuery-inserted DOM elements without requerying for element after insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950318/getting-jquery-inserted-dom-elements-without-requerying-for-element-after-insert)

Is there a way to store a newly prepended element (with jQuery) into a var?

I want to do something like this:

```
var new_div = $('#my-div').prepend('<div>Something new</div>');

setTimeout(function () {
    new_div.remove();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: This question has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655627/jquery-append-object-remove-it-with-delay

Comment: Also having a look at the documentation helps: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to store the newly created `div` in your variable, you have to start with the creation of the `div`, then use [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/):

```
var new_div = $('<div>Something new</div>').prependTo('#my-div');

setTimeout(function () {
    new_div.remove();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newItem = $('<div>Something new</div>');
new_div.prepend(newItem);

setTimeout(function () {
    newItem.remove();
}, 2000);
```

Assuming `new_div` is a jquery object in the DOM ( like another div)

Working sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/exQTa/

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_div = $('<div>Something new</div>');

$('#my-div').prepend(new_div);

var timer = setTimeout(function () {
    new_div.remove();
}, 2000);
```

Or more jQuery'ish:

```
$('<div>Something new</div>').prependTo('#my-div').delay(2000).queue(function() {
    $(this).remove(); 
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aGg6d/)